# I don't have access my codes in the runner in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, containers, github-actions

I created the following "main.yml" file.

```
name: Deploy

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:

      - name: test 
        run: ls -al && cd .. && ls -al

      - name: Create SSH key
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
          echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/private.key
          sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private.key
          ssh-keyscan -H ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          echo "Host ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}
            User ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private.key" > ~/.ssh/config
            cat ~/.ssh/config
        shell: bash
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}

      - name: test-remote
        run: rsync -r ${{secrets.SSH_USER}}@${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}:~/${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}

      - name: Deploy with rsync
        run: cd .. && ls -al && rsync -avz ./ ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}:/var/www/${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
```

However, I cannot access my codes in the github repository as seen in the following output in the runner.

Maybe I'm using the rsync command incorrectly, so I tried to output with ls and even to output from its parent directory. How do you think I can solve it?

[image]

Comment: What do you intend to do with rsync? The code is already checked out when your runner starts.

Comment: I'm trying to send the whole code over ssh to my own server via rsync.

Comment: I'm not an rsync expert either, but to me that output looks succesful.

Comment: I solved it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Junior things... I forgot to checkout in the beginning. I added checkout to the beginning of the steps as below and the problem was solved.

```
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@main
```